# Replace all specific values in data.frame with values from another data.frame sequentially R

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, match

I have a data.frame (df1) and I want to include a single, most recent age for each of my samples from another data.frame (df2):

```
df1$age <- df2$age_9[match(df1$Sample_ID, df2$Sample_ID)]
```

The problem is that in df2 there are 9 columns for age, as each one indicates the age at a specific check-up date (age_1 is from the first visit, age_9 is the age at the 9th visit) and patients dont make all their visits.

How do I add the most recently obtained age from a non empty check up date?

aka, if age_9 == "." replace "." with age_8 then if age_8 == "." replace "." with age_7 ... etc

From this:

```
View(df1)
Sample Age
1      50
2      .
3      .
```

To:

```
View(df1)
Sample Age
1      50
2      49
3      30
```

From the data df2

```
View(df2)
Sample Age_1 Age_2 Age_3
1      40    42    44
2      35    49    .
3      30    .     .
```

This is my attempt:

```
df1$age[which(df1$age == ".")] <- df2$age_8[match(df1$Sample_ID, df2$Sample_ID)]
```

Comment: you should `stack` up your age dataset so as to have it in a long format. Then you can be able to use `ifelse` or rather any other function of your choice

Comment: INot clear about the format.  May be `nm1 <- grep("age_\\d+", names(df2), value = TRUE); df1[nm1] <- lapply(df2[nm1], function(x) x[match(df1$Sample_ID, df2$Sample_ID)])`

Comment: @akrun so that put each of the age columns for df2 into df1 but I just want one column with the most recent age. I updated the question a little to clarify

Comment: @SkyScraper Have you tried the code in the comments

Comment: @akrun yes, your code just added all the columns with age information from df2 into df1. Onyambu code I couldnt stack to work as expected but i can try again

Comment: Can you provide your data in a reproducible format that we can copy? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `base R`, we can use `max.col` to return the `last` column index for each row, where the 'Age' columns are not `.`, `cbind` with sequence of rows to return  a row/column index, extract the elements and change the 'Age' column in 'df1', where the 'Age' is `.`

```
df1$Age <- ifelse(df1$Age == ".", df2[-1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df2)), 
        max.col(df2[-1] != ".", "last"))], df1$Age)

df1 <- type.convert(df1, as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
df1
#  Sample Age
#1      1  50
#2      2  49
#3      3  30
```

---

or using `tidyverse` by reshaping into 'long' format and then do a join after `slice`ing the last row grouped by 'Sample'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>% 
    mutate(across(starts_with('Age'), as.integer)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Age'), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
    group_by(Sample) %>% 
    slice_tail(n = 1) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-name) %>%
    right_join(df1) %>%
    transmute(Sample, Age = coalesce(as.integer(Age), value))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Sample   Age
#   <int> <int>
#1      1    50
#2      2    49
#3      3    30
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Sample = 1:3, Age = c("50", ".", ".")), 
       class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Sample = 1:3, Age_1 = c(40L, 35L, 30L), Age_2 = c("42", 
"49", "."), Age_3 = c("44", ".", ".")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: dammit, if works with your data but when I try to run: ```age1_age9[-1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(age1_age9)), max.col(age1_age9[-1] != ".", "last"))]``` I get Error: Subscript `cbind(...)` is a matrix, it must be of type logical. I am trying to work out what the issue is

Comment: UPDATE: the class of the object was "tbl_df"  "tbl"   "data.frame" instead of just "data.frame" so using as.data.frame() fixed the issue

Comment: the first solution assumes the lengths and order of df1 and df2 are the same

Comment: I guess I would add the "by" operator (?) of right_join but right_join will auto pick a varriable to join by if it isnt provided. thanks much

Comment: @SkyScraper you can do `right_join(df1, by = "Sample")` and if the column names are different then `right_join(df1, by = c("Sample1" = "Sample2"))`